# Xpath locator in checkbox

Tags: selenium, xpath, checkbox

I am learning selenium and want to select check box in amazon page. I went to amazon site and searched for dresses. On the left hand side it displays brands and I want to select Relipop checkbox. I tried the following code and it didn't work

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='p_89/Relipop']/span/a/div/label/i)")).click();
```

Could you please help me and i appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try xpath like this:

```
//li[@id='p_89/Relipop']/span/a//span[text()='Relipop']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pay attention here

```
[@id='p_89/Relipop']
```

`p_89` looks dynamic in nature what it means is, it may change based on location or even if we refresh etc.

I see this HTML for the mentioned button

```
<a data-routing="" class="a-link-normal s-navigation-item" tabindex="-1" href="/s?k=dresses&amp;i=fashion&amp;bbn=7141123011&amp;rh=n%3A7141123011&amp;dc&amp;qid=1632119503&amp;rnid=2528832011&amp;ref=sr_nr_p_89_1">
  <div class="a-checkbox a-checkbox-fancy s-navigation-checkbox aok-float-left"><label><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" checked=""><i class="a-icon a-icon-checkbox"></i><span class="a-label a-checkbox-label"></span></label></div>
  <span class="a-size-base a-color-base a-text-bold" dir="auto">Relipop</span>
</a>
```

Basically we have 4 ways to click in **Selenium-Java bindings.**

I will use this xpath

```
//span[text()='Relipop']/ancestor::a
```

**Code trial 1 :**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Relipop']/ancestor::a")).click();
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Relipop']/ancestor::a"))).click();
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Relipop']/ancestor::a"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
WebElement button  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Relipop']/ancestor::a"));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(button).click().build().perform();
```

to `click` on `check box`, in my experience `JS works` absolutely flawless.

so please start with `code trial 3`, and if that does not work, try other methods.